# Showing that $\sum a_n < \sum b_n $ if $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$ and for at least one n $a_n < b_n$

Tags: analysis

Question: suppose $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are convergent series of non-negative numbers. Show that if $a_n \leq b_n$ for all n and if $a_n < b_n $ for at least one n, then $\sum a_n < \sum b_n$.

Thoughts: I have already shown previously that if for two convergent sequences if $a_n \leq b_n$ for all n then lim $ a_n \leq $ lim $b_n$ so if I take the smallest index $n$ such that $a_n < b_n$ then there will be a finite amount of terms $a_1 + ... + a_{n} < b_1 + ... + b_{n}$ and then $\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}a_n \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}b_n$ which are convergent (?), thus $ a_1 + ... + a_{n} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}a_n = \sum a_n  < b_1 + ... + b_{n} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}b_n =  \sum b_n$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if you're confused about why $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k$ converges, consider the sequence $\{c_k\}$ where $c_k=0$ for $k \leq n$ and $c_k=a_k$ for $k > n$ and apply comparison test.